# how do I get sets of data with xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

My below code retrieves a series of images from the search results of a site and also the corresponding `age` data. It works fine however I get a list of images followed by a list of the information in the `age` field.

`img img img img age age age age` and so on.

How do I combine these so I can display them in sets: `img age` `img age` `img age`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);

    $html = new DOMDocument();
    @$html->loadHtmlFile('http://www.site.com/searchresults.html');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
    $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='age']" );

    $tags = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {

            $image =  $tag->getAttribute('src');
            echo '<img src='. $image .' alt="image" ><br>';
    }


    foreach ($nodelist as $n)
    {
        echo $n->nodeValue."<br>";
    }

?>
```

Sample page, I want to extract the `img` source `title` data from `<div class="age" title="30 usa">`:

```
<div id="sr-15763292" class="search-result">
    <div class="thumb-wrapper">
      <a class="bioLink" href="http://www.site.com/user/"  title="View user"><img src="http://www.site.com/img/15763292.jpg" class="thumb" alt="user" width="140" height="105"></a>

      <p class="status"><a href="http://www.site.com/user/" >Online</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="rating">
      <div class="rating-stars rating4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="age" title="30 usa">
     <p>30</p>
     <p class="gender m">m</p>
     <p>USA</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p class="headline">Hello there.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to provide a representative XML document. Please, edit the question and specify this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer if we don't know what the HTML looks like! Assuming it looks something like this

```
<div class="age"><p>21</p>
    <img src="a.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="age"><p>51</p>
    <img src="b.jpg" />
</div>
```

you need to find each div and then find the image inside each div. getElementsByTagName() will give you a list even if there's only one result, so use item() to fetch the first.

```
error_reporting(-1);

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('results.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='age']" );

foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
    $tags = $node->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $image =  $tags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo '<img src="'. $image .'" alt="image" ><br>';
    echo $node->textContent . '<br>';
}
```

If the HTML is like this

```
<div class="age"><p>21</p></div><img src="a.jpg" />
```

you can try

```
 $node->nextSibling()
```

As a general point trace through the HTML and think how do I get from A to B? Go forwards? backwards? up to parent, to the next node and down again ...?

Comment: That works but gets more information than I want. How do I do something like 'getElementsByTagName' but for a certain class?